# ExpressJS : req is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, xmlhttprequest

I try to post data with XMLHttpRequest to a service made with ExpressJS.

Server side in index.js :

```
 app.post('/add',url.add);
```

Servier side in url.js :

```
exports.add = function(req, res){
  var urlToAdd = req.body;
  console.log(urlToAdd);
};
```

Client side :

```
<input id="url" required="true"/>
<button id="addButton">Ajouter</button>
```

JS Client side :

```
document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
var url = document.getElementById("url").value;

var xhr_object = null; 

if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
     xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
else { 
    alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les objets XMLHTTPRequest..."); 
         return; 
} 

xhr_object.open("POST", "/add", true);

xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function() { 
     if(xhr_object.readyState == 4) {
        //alert(xhr_object.responseText); // DEBUG MODE
        //document.write(xhr_object.responseText);
        eval(xhr_object.responseText);
     }
    return xhr_object.readyState;
}

var param = "url="+url;
xhr_object.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr_object.send(param);

});
```

When I want to send data, `req.body` is `undefined`.

Comment: Which [middleware](http://expressjs.com/resources/middleware.html) is the `app` currently [using](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use)? [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body) is "*populated with the use of a body-parsing middleware such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer).*"

Comment: Also, the parameters being passed to `.send()` may require [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to be valid. A simple name like `url` is fine as is, but its value probably isn't. You can use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode it -- `var param = "url=" + encodeURIComponent(url);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
When you want to get the body of POST request with express use :

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Then you can do :

```
var urlToAdd = req.body.url;
```